# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when trying to edit or view code

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My Visual Studio has been behaving oddly. It was working fine for over a year and I took a break from it for about a month. Now every time I try to do anything on it VS crashes. I tried uninstalling. Switching to VS2015 and it still crashed, so I switched back to VS2013 and it still crashes. Honestly I don't know what the cause of the issue is as I don't believe I've changed anything.

I just tried starting a new project and writing "hello world" and it crashed before I could finish typing it up.

Comment: I usually reinstall Windows, most proposals otherwise are like trying to plug up a dam with band-aids (futile)

Comment: I could reinstall Windows, but part of me would like to know what the issue is to begin with.

Comment: Well VS is closed source, these kinds of things happen all the time. I you really want an answer you will need to post a lot more details, for example what is crashing along with steps to recreate.

Comment: Typing anything into the program triggers "crashing". It happens within a minute of typing. The window pops up saying that Visual Studio has stopped working and it attempts to restart. If it happens twice in a row then Visual Studio actually closes.